# cppcheck: index out of bounds condition when run on C code

Tags: arrays, c, cppcheck

```
main.c|50|arrayIndexOutOfBoundsCond : warning : Either the condition 'j==0' is redundant or the array 'x[10][20]' is accessed at index x[19][0], which is out of bounds.|
main.c|52|arrayIndexOutOfBoundsCond : warning : Either the condition 'j==10-1' is redundant or the array 'x[10][20]' is accessed at index x[19][9], which is out of bounds.|
main.c|54|arrayIndexOutOfBoundsCond : warning : Either the condition 'i==20-1' is redundant or the array 'x[10][20]' is accessed at index x[19][*], which is out of bounds.|
main.c|74|arrayIndexOutOfBounds : error : Array 'x[10][20]' accessed at index x[19][*], which is out of bounds.|
```

that's all the errors i keep getting by cppcheck

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 10
#define M 20
void firstelements(double x[N][M]);
void printtable(double x[N][M]);
void calculatetemp(double x[N][M]);

int main() {
  double table[N][M];
  firstelements(table);
  printf("time:0\n\n");
  printtable(table);
  printf("\n\n");
  calculatetemp(table);
  return 0;
}

void firstelements(double x[N][M]) {
  double up, down, right, left, interior;
  double upleft, upright, downleft, downright;
  int i, j;
  printf("please enter the temperature of the up side: ");
  scanf("%lf", &up);
  printf("please enter the temperature of the down side: ");
  scanf("\n%lf", &down);
  printf("please enter the temperature of the left side: ");
  scanf("\n%lf", &right);
  printf("please enter the temperature of the right side: ");
  scanf("\n%lf", &left);
  printf("please enter the temperature of the interior: ");
  scanf("\n%lf", &interior);
  upleft = (up + left) / 2;
  upright = (up + right) / 2;
  downleft = (down + left) / 2;
  downright = (down + right) / 2;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        if (j == 0) {
          x[i][j] = upleft;
        } else if (j == M - 1) {
          x[i][j] = upright;
        } else {
          x[i][j] = up;
        }
      }
      if (i == N - 1) {
        if (j == 0) {
          x[i][j] = downleft;
        } else if (j == M - 1) {
          x[i][j] = downright;
        } else {
          x[i][j] = down;
        }
      }
      if (i > 0 && i < N - 1) {
        if (j == 0) {
          x[i][j] = left;
        } else if (j == M - 1) {
          x[i][j] = right;
        } else {
          x[i][j] = interior;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return;
}
void printtable(double x[N][M]) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
      printf("%6.2f   ", x[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return;
}
void calculatetemp(double x[N][M]) {
  printf("calculatetemp\n");
  return;
}
```

Comment: You're running a C++ code checker on C code. The result will not be very useful.

Comment: But the errors seem very precise and clear!

Comment: i have to run cppcheck according to exercise pronunciation

Comment: @MarcusMüller From a quick scan, page 15 of the [manual](https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/manual.pdf) states [cppcheck](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck) works with C (C11 by default), although the rest of the documentation is rather unclear ("C/C++" is such a worthless term). Is OP missing a flag to enable a "C mode"? Misnamed files perhaps?

Comment: @Oka if it goes by file name, then `main.c` would sound like C :)

Comment: The errors seem precise and clear ... and wrong!? I can't see how `i` should become larger than `N`. Especially as the locations are within that block `if (i == N - 1)` where `i==9`, not  `19`.

Comment: Are you sure that the posted code is the one that generates these errors? Which line is line 50 (and the others mentioned)?

Comment: @Bob__ I ran a code formatter on the code, but I made sure to not add or remove any line breaks, so

Comment: @mplamplampla how did you run `cppcheck`? I simply can't reproduce

Comment: i used code::blocks to write my code , in order to run cpp check i had to download it .In order to run cpp check i simply go to plugins and then i press the button that says Cppcheck . It's not the first time i have done , it is judt the first time that it gives me errors

Comment: @Bob__ yes that is the code , i just can't understand why these errors are there . I should have propably write the lines next to the code .

Comment: Does it complain, if you write it [this way](https://godbolt.org/z/jeK715vxT)?

Comment: @Bob__ it does complain because i write code in C90 but if i run it in C11 it doesn't give me any errors . I solved the errors based on what you wrote int that code

Comment: Like @MarcusMüller I am not able to reproduce this with any version of Cppcheck. Which version are you using?

Comment: @mplamplampla I really tried everything, and I can't get `cppcheck` to produce your errors with this program. Can you run `cppcheck --version` from the command line and tell us what it told you? What does `cppcheck --enable=all yourfile.c` give you (replace `yourfile.c` with the path to your actual source code file)?